# Changing pixel size of georeferenced historical map

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, united-states, historical-maps

I have georeferenced an old toposheet from the US Army toposheet repository.

However, when I look at the georeferenced map, it looks very grainy (i.e. pixel size is too big). How do I make it easier to read the features of the toposheet in QGIS or what would be the right horizontal and vertical target resolutions in the transformation settings?

Projection: EPSG:4326

[image]

Comment: Which CRS is the map in?

Comment: EPSG 4326 is the wrong CRS, it uses degrees as unit, you are trying to georeference a quadrangle toposheet that uses a different crs. Can you show the original bottom center of the scanned map?

Answer (score 5):

The original scan of the map can be found here: http://legacy.lib.utexas.edu/maps/ams/india/nc-43-03.jpg

I have enlarged the details on central bottom of the map
[image: scalebars and description]
The CRS of the blue lines can be identified as EPSG:24374, Kalianpur 1880 / India zone IV

The map projection proper is transverse mercator, likely also on Kalianpur 1880, eyeballing the central meridian halfway the map edges at 75°45' East, guessing a standard central scale factor of 0.9996. The following proj4 string worked for me (using the Kalianpur 1975 datum definition):

```
+proj=tmerc +x_0=500000.0 +lon_0=75.75 +k_0=0.9996 +units=m +a=6377299.151 +b=6356098.145120132 +towgs84=295,736,257,0,0,0,0 +no_defs
```

[image: georeferenced]

Measuring the scalebar, I find 133 pixels per 5 km, so a pixel size of 35 meters gives the same resolution as the original scan.